# How to make a JS counter permanently retain the number of counts?

Tags: javascript, html, tumblr-html

I'm trying to make a page on my tumblr that has a button on it, which counts how many times it's been pressed. I've gotten it to work, but a browser close or refresh clears the value, and clicks from different people don't stack. Here's what I have:

```html
<body>
  <div class="main">

    <h3>Click Counter</h3>
    <button id="clickme">Click me: 0</button>

    <h5>Filler Text</h5>

  </div>
  <script>
    var button = document.getElementById("clickme"),
        count = 0;
        
    button.onclick = function() {
      count += 1;
      button.innerHTML = "Click me: " + count;
    };
  </script>
</body>
```

This makes the button count up when pressed, but I want it to behave like so:

User #1 clicks twice. Counter reads two.

User #2 visits the page, counter is already at two, user clicks 3 times. Counter is at 5.

User #3 visits, counter is still at 5 for them as well, etc.

As of right now, each user visits the page and the value starts at zero. Help?

Comment: You'll need to save the clicks on a backend. Do you have a backend that can do this?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I'm trying to get it working on a tumblr page, so I don't have to host any files myself. Would I have to set that up using some kind of PHP server?

Comment: PHP, or Node, or anything really, such that you can save the current count and perform the sort of programmatic logic required. If you can't alter the Tumblr response sufficiently, you could call your own external API on some other (non-Tumblr) server, do you have one of those you can use?

Comment: I don't. The tumblr pages are entirely front-end, but would it be possible to use another tumblr page in this fashion? And if not, I guess I'll just have to set up my own backend?

Comment: @KeithO'Donnell you can use google firebase for saving counts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

javascript runs on the browser and store all the variable in the browser so the scope of a variable is in the browser. you can use local storage but if all user uses the same browser which is not your need so only way to persist data is to save count (data) into the server and fetch count (data) on a load of the page.

you can use `firebase real-time database` if you don't have any server.

[Getting started with Firebase real-time database for the web](https://medium.com/evenbit/getting-started-with-firebase-real-time-database-for-the-web-f53b527aae27)

Comment: That sounds like it'll do the trick- how do I set it up? I have almost no clue how to use it or how to link it to my page.

Comment: check the medium tutorial added in answer

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your needs, you could use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

```
count = localStorage.getItem('count');
count = parseInt(count); // because localstorage stores everything in strings

// First time the value does not exist...
if(count == null) {
  count = 0; 
}

button.onclick = function() {
  count += 1;
  button.innerHTML = "Click me: " + count;
  localStorage.setItem("count", count);
};
```

This is not a server side solution. It's also less reliable as it can be cleared by the user anytime.

Answer (score 0):

As I have understant form your question you want to retain the user click count, there is 3 scenerio

1. User visits form Single machine Single browser (rare situation)
           in this you can use local storage
2. User visits form  Single machine multiple browser 
            In this case you have to save it in server side
3. User visits form multiple machine multiple browser 
        In this case you have to save it in server side

Both case 2,3 are same , you need to save it in server.

A common way to do this , put you counter in db and an REST end point and call that endpoint on page each page load to take the counter form the server and also after clicking update on the server by similar end point

Suggesting learning: Client side : AJAX (Jquery)  , Server side :  REST API , DB (MySql,ets)